# Read Number of lines in Large Text File VB6

Tags: vba, text, vb6

I have text File of Size 230MB. I want to Count Number of Lines OF that File.

I tried "**`Scripting.FileSystemOblect`**" but it goes out Of memory.

Please Help.

Thanks.

Comment: `UBound` has been supported since at least [QBasic](http://www.freewebs.com/computerghost/QBasic/Commands.htm#U)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normal Windows line breaks are CRLF, so you can count the LFs and add 1 to the count in cases where the last line of your files doesn't have one after it.

In true VB (i.e. VB5, VB6, etc.) you can make use of the byte-oriented String operations to speed many tasks.  If we can assume the text files contain ANSI then this is pretty fast:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Main()
    Const BUFSIZE As Long = 100000
    Dim T0 As Single
    Dim LfAnsi As String
    Dim F As Integer
    Dim FileBytes As Long
    Dim BytesLeft As Long
    Dim Buffer() As Byte
    Dim strBuffer As String
    Dim BufPos As Long
    Dim LineCount As Long

    T0 = Timer()
    LfAnsi = StrConv(vbLf, vbFromUnicode)
    F = FreeFile(0)
    Open "big.txt" For Binary Access Read As #F
    FileBytes = LOF(F)
    ReDim Buffer(BUFSIZE - 1)
    BytesLeft = FileBytes
    Do Until BytesLeft = 0
        If BufPos = 0 Then
            If BytesLeft < BUFSIZE Then ReDim Buffer(BytesLeft - 1)
            Get #F, , Buffer
            strBuffer = Buffer 'Binary copy of bytes.
            BytesLeft = BytesLeft - LenB(strBuffer)
            BufPos = 1
        End If
        Do Until BufPos = 0
            BufPos = InStrB(BufPos, strBuffer, LfAnsi)
            If BufPos > 0 Then
                LineCount = LineCount + 1
                BufPos = BufPos + 1
            End If
        Loop
    Loop
    Close #F
    'Add 1 to LineCount if last line of your files do not
    'have a trailing CrLf.
    MsgBox "Counted " & Format$(LineCount, "#,##0") & " lines in" & vbNewLine _
         & Format$(FileBytes, "#,##0") & " bytes of text." & vbNewLine _
         & Format$(Timer() - T0, "0.0#") & " seconds."
End Sub
```

Given a 7,000,000 line file of 293MB it only takes 0.7 seconds here.  But note that I had not rebooted to ensure that the file wasn't cached when I ran that test.  Without caching (i.e. after a reboot) I'd expect it to take as long as 5 times that.

Converting to handle Unicode text files is fairly simple.  Just replace the B-functions by the non-B equivalents, make sure you set BUFSIZE to a multiple of 2, and search for `vbLf` instead of an ANSI LF byte.

Comment: Thanks.. Its Working really fast compare to others.

Comment: Hmm, well I guess your `UBound()` started working.  You're welcome.

Comment: 1.6 GB file with 11004037 no. of lines in ~20 seconds

Comment: This is blazing fast. Thank you so much! @Bob77

Comment: Thankyou Very Fast! ✨

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by reading each line into the same variable. There's no need to save all the lines:

```
dim s as string
dim n as integer

open "filename.txt" for input as 1

n = 0
do while not eof(1)
  line input #1, s
  n = n + 1
  loop
```

This has not been tested, and it's been a while since I've done any VB6, but it should be close.

Comment: It will take more time because of looping into large file.

Comment: That's true. Another way that might be faster is be to use the FileSystemObject to read the entire file into an array of bytes (use LOF to see how many), then count the occurrences of chr(13) and/or chr(10) in the array.

Comment: +1 FileSystemObject will also be slow, as it also reads the whole file. If you *really* want speed you could use a [memory mapped file](http://vb.mvps.org/articles/ap199910.asp) but its a lot of work and quite advanced.

Answer (score 2):

This takes about 6 seconds for me on a 480mb binary file with 1mil+ 0xD (vbcr)

```
Dim buff() As Byte
Dim hF As Integer
Dim i As Long, n As Long

hF = FreeFile(0)

Open "c:\windows\Installer\2f91fd.msp" For Binary Access Read As #hF
ReDim buff(LOF(hF) - 1)
Get #hF, , buff()
Close #hF

For i = 0 To UBound(buff)
    If buff(i) = 13 Then n = n + 1
Next

MsgBox n
```

Comment: Thanks For the reply But Ubound is not support In my VB6.

Comment: UBound is supported in every version of VB6, what are you using?

Comment: i tried with 1.6 GB file and it failed(Out of Memory) on ReDim buff(LOF(hF) - 1)