# VBA code slow to run the first time each day

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have a issue, which i thought was to do with network drives but now i have tested and its not the issue.

There is 2000 files(totaling 328MB) that match, used in the test and it takes about 1.4seconds to complete this anytime i run it, EXCEPT the first time each day, when it takes anywhere from 30secs to 60 secs.

I thought Dir was causing the issue but its definitively inside the loop that is slow.

Would File caching be causing this issue? 
Is there a better way to load in the first line of a large quantity of files quickly

```
'Get All Filenames
sAllFiles = Dir("C:\Folder\" & sFile & "??.???")

'Loop through each File
Do While Len(sAllFiles) > 0

    sCurrentFileName = sAllFiles
    sCurrentFilePath = "C:\Folder\" & sCurrentFileName

    'Read 1st line from each file
    Open sCurrentFilePath For Input As #1

        Line Input #1, sFirstLine

    Close #1

     vRowData = Split(sFirstLine, "~")
     '(Write data to array code here)

    sAllFiles = Dir

Loop
```

Comment: This sounds like caching is happening.  If so, the 30-60 seconds needed to read the files has to happen _somewhere_.  Where else could it happen if not in your code?

Comment: Does the full 328MB need to be read? Is there a way to just read the first line with out putting the full file into memory?

Comment: Read the accepted answer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598691/read-number-of-lines-in-large-text-file-vb6), which mentions that reading can be significantly slower without caching.