# VBA Read Large Text File and Delete unwanted text lines

Tags: vba, file, ms-access, text, binary

I am trying to clean up a large text file (repeated header/trailers) to import into access table.
I am refrencing this prior post: [Read Number of lines in Large Text File VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598691/read-number-of-lines-in-large-text-file-vb6)

What i am trying to do is switch:  Open s_inp_file For Input As inp_file_num   to   Open s_inp_file For Binary Access Read As #inp_file_num  fora binary read to make the process faster. The Input method takes too long. The problem is in my code i cannot use Line Input when opening as Binary and I get a run time error #62 - input reached past end of file in the loop. Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
Sub Scrub_TextLines(s_inp_file As String, s_out_file As String)
    Dim inp_file_num As Integer
    Dim out_file_num As Integer
    Dim text_line As String
    Dim file_content As String
    Dim buffer() As Byte
    Dim i As Long

    Const remove_text1 As String = "REPORTING SERVICE"
'    Const remove_text2 As String = "PRODUCT TYPE -"
'    Const remove_text3 As String = "ALL REPORT"
    Const remove_text4 As String = "CLIENT NAME"
    Const remove_text5 As String = "CLIENT ID"
    Const remove_text6 As String = "TY YEAR"
    Const remove_text7 As String = "CLIENT-ID2"
    Const remove_text8 As String = "----"

    inp_file_num = FreeFile
    Open s_inp_file For Binary Access Read As #inp_file_num
    ReDim buffer(LOF(inp_file_num) - 1)
    Get #inp_file_num, , buffer
        Do Until EOF(inp_file_num)
            Line Input #inp_file_num, text_line
            If text_line <> "" And _
                Left(text_line, 4) <> "    " And _
                    InStr(1, text_line, remove_text1, vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
                    InStr(1, text_line, remove_text4, vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
                    InStr(1, text_line, remove_text5, vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
                    InStr(1, text_line, remove_text6, vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
                    InStr(1, text_line, remove_text7, vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
                    InStr(1, text_line, remove_text8, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

                file_content = file_content & text_line & vbCrLf
'                Debug.Print file_content
            End If
        Loop
    Close #inp_file_num

    out_file_num = FreeFile
    Open s_out_file For Output As out_file_num
        Print #out_file_num, file_content
    Close #out_file_num
End Sub
```

Comment: Possibly exceeding the INTEGER limit of 32 thousandish? Change your variables to LONG?

Comment: I think it's because of how your loop is structured. Your do-until loop evaluates the body before checking `EOF` to make sure you still have lines to read. Try changing your `Do ... Until` loop to a `Do While ... Loop` loop. I believe `Do While Not EOF(inp_file_num)` should work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses -
I just attempted changing the loop and received the same error in the line 'Line Input #inp_file_num, text_line'.

Also, the integers are in reference to the file allocation (FreeFile) so it would not increase much.

Comment: You can probably stay with the original text-based line-by-line approach if instead of building up the "output" file in memory you write each line out directly to a different file.  Or at least use a "stringbuilder" approach to create the output: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67596/a-lightning-fast-stringbuilder

Comment: i just read the code, i will try to implement this tomorrow and see how it works - thanks for the suggestion, looks very interesting!

Comment: one note to add, i do have a print to output file method, however the only caveat to that approach is that the text file contains some non print characters that break up the print to file process - so it was a two step approach, removing chr(26) substitute character and then header/trailer remover. my only concern was running into other char that would break the process so i wanted to see what else could be done.

Comment: @Tim Williams  - i just incorporated the StringBuilder method - very impressive! it spat out the output file in 4s (~169K rows) as opposed to 3.45m using the Print to output method and even longer using memory concatenation method. I don't know how to close this on comments section but this is the solution i will be going with. thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the update - repeated string concatenation can bite you if you're not aware of the performance implication...

Comment: followed @Tim Williams suggestion for StringBuilder:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67596/a-lightning-fast-stringbuilder

Comment: I VERY but VERY much doubt you see any increase in performance by flipping from a "binary" read from a line by line. the "line read" is fast since it grabs  the WHOLE line in one shot - you not increase this speed by switching to binary - and in fact you likely will see a slow down. Stick with a full line input. You can read 100,000 lines per second that way - it not clear where your "slow part" is but the line input approach is NOT your problem nor your bottle neck.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
Do Until EOF(inp_file_num)
```

To:

```
Do While Not EOF(inp_file_num)
```

Comment: same error unfortunately, from what I read, when the Binary method is used, you cannot use Line Input, perhaps it is strictly used for strings? I am just not sure the best way to modify it to make this work.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the following line:

```
Get #inp_file_num, , buffer
```

If you read all the file content, the pointer is located at the end of file, so that you can not read a new line.